# В чём разница между su и sudo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, su

вписываю команду su, ввожу пароль, и мне выбрасывает ошибку.

а когда sudo, то все нормально.

В чем может быть ошибка?

дистрибутив: ubuntu.

Comment: sudo su - наверно так надо

Comment: потому что su требует рутового пароля.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

программа *su* служит для выполнения от имени указанного пользователя (по умолчанию — *root*) указанной команды/программы (по умолчанию — той программы, что определена в качестве оболочки (*shell*) для указанного пользователя) и запрашивает она пароль указанного пользователя.

о программе *sudo* можно сказать почти то же самое, за двумя исключениями:

1. нет «программы по умолчанию». для запуска оболочки, определённой для указанного пользователя, надо передать программе опцию `-i`.
2. по умолчанию запрашивается не пароль указанного пользователя, а пароль пользователя, выполняющего программу *sudo*. какому пользователю, какие программы и от чьего имени можно запускать, определяется содержимым конфигурационного файла `/etc/sudoers` (редактируется с помощью программы `visudo`).

---

так что «ошибки» у вас нет. просто пароль, который вы вводите после запуска программы *su*, не подходит к учётной записи *root* (скорее всего, пароль вообще не задан, и это нормально и правильно).

Comment: а где ты вписывал этот пароль root?

Comment: @darkwoolf, нигде. его в «обычной жизни» и не требуется. sudo команда — запросит пароль текущего пользователя. если, конечно, в конф. файле `/etc/sudoers` не указано, что данный пользователь (при выполнении данной команды и/или от имени указанного пользователя) может не вводить пароль вообще.

Comment: У меня рут-пароль задан, т. к. временами используется прямой логин, а su не используется. А sudo - только если требуется pacman.

Answer (score 1):

нужно создать пароль для пользователя root

```
sudo passwd root
```

После можно входить под пользователем root

Comment: по-моему скромному мнению, совет скорее вреден, нежели полезен.

Comment: @alexander barakin  , Когда Я начинал рабтать с Linux, команды `sudo` небыло и очень быстро учился грамотно работать, на одном компе с простым пользователем и привегилерованым. Конечно работать из под root  быстрее, но нужно быть ОЧЕНЬ внимательным.

Comment: *Когда Я начинал рабтать с Linux, команды sudo небыло* — звучит несколько двусмысленно ввиду того, что [программа linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#Creation) написана **значительно** позже [программы sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo#History).

Comment: Но В linux эта программа пришла недавно. В начале века в дистрибутивы ее не выкладывали и даже в справочниках не упоминали. (Как звучит `В начале века`)))

Comment: *В начале века в дистрибутивы ее не выкладывали* — вы ошибаетесь. например, эта программ [присутствовала](https://archive.debian.net/bo/sudo) в версии *debian gnu/linux* с кодовым названием *bo*, которая [выпущена в 1997 году](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Debian_releases#Debian_1.3_.28Bo.29). разумеется, программа присутствовала и в других дистрибутивах, и в более раннее время. просто подтверждение найти несколько сложнее, чем в пару-тройку кликов.

Comment: Ради интереса посмотрел [старые дистрибутивы](https://old-linux.com/) которыми начинал пользоватся действительно команда sudo  уже шла в них. Но она шла отдельным пакетом. Поэтому в [справочниках которые можно было достать](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/138787/Speiinauer,_Figgins,_Hekman_-_Linux._Spravochnik.pdf) оней обычно нислова.

Comment: Команда `su` в отличие от `sudo` при правильном пароле сработает даже от простого пользователя без полномочий разрешённых sudoers. Это может быть удобно, когда за компьютером обычно работает пользователь без администраторских прав.

Answer (score 1):

Разница большая. Как минимум, в окружении. Как минимум, домашние каталоги `~` будут разными. Если таки хотите использовать шелл от рута - `sudo su -` в помощь.

А вообще - почитайте-ка для начала три темы:

`man man`

`man su`

`man sudo`

Comment: `man man` - тонкий троллинг )