# Основы безопасности от системного администратора

Tags: linux, безопасность, sudo, password

Ввел в консоли `Ubuntu` команду:

```
$ sudo mc
```

Оно мне выдало такое:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

И просит пароль. Что это? Мне просто нужно получить доступ к консоли от рута.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русском варианте эта фраза звучит так:

```
Мы полагаем, что ваш системный администратор изложил вам основы
безопасности. Как правило, всё сводится к трём следующим правилам:

    №1) Уважайте частную жизнь других.
    №2) Думайте, прежде что-то вводить.
    №3) С большой властью приходит большая ответственность.
```

А пароль `sudo` надо знать, иначе доступ к консоли от рута невозможен.

Comment: «Пароль sudo» — это пароль текущего пользователя. Будет крайне странно, если пользователь не знает свой собственный пароль

Comment: [и вообще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522740/178576)

Comment: Пароля sudo нет если конечно у вас не добавлен пользователь с именем sudo

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь, что текущий пользователь в группе `sudo` или `wheel`:

```
~$ id
```

Также пользователя можно внести в sudo группу напрямую:

```
~# visudo
```

На некоторых дистрибутивах нужно перезайти пользователю, чтоб права были *«активированы»*.

Как минимум кто-то с рут правами должен добавить непривилегированного пользователя в группу sudo, и пользователь должен знать свой пароль.