# При выполнении команды от имени sudo выдаёт ошибку

Tags: sudo, wsl

При выполнении команды от имени sudo выдаёт ошибку `*username* is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported`.
Пробовал зайти через команду `su`, также не выходит. Консоль пишет `su: Authentication failure`

Comment: обращайтесь к администратору данного компьютера.

Comment: я администратор, ввожу верный пароль в su и он фейлится

Comment: Значит вы на самом деле забыли пароль.

Comment: В таком случае он бы писал фразу `Sorry, try again.`

Comment: Окей, давайте начнём с самого начала - почему вы решили, что sudo вообще должен работать для вашего пользователя?

Comment: потому что я всегда работал с судо (так как я и есть админ) и проблем не было.

Comment: `ввожу верный пароль в su` — 1. *su* (также как и *sudo*) — это программа. так, для справки. 2. если вы вызываете её без указания, от чьего имени вам надо выполнить программу/сеанс оболочки, то запрашивается у вас пароль **пользователя `root`**. видимо, вы либо не устанавливали этот пароль вообще, либо вводите его неправильно. 3. [ещё для справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522691/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему просто сбросом в виндовой консольке ВСЛки (у меня на ней все равно ничего важного не было)

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что вашего пользователя нет в файле `/etc/sudoers`. Эту ошибку можно исправить с помощью режима восстановления.

- Командой `tail /var/log/auth.log` можно узнать, кто пытался получить доступ root. Примерный вывод:

```
Jul 26 16:08:16 surface-PC sudo:  surface : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/surface ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
Jul 26 16:08:17 surface-PC sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 26 16:08:17 surface-PC su: (to root) surface on pts/0
Jul 26 16:08:17 surface-PC su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

- Перезагружаем компьютер, в меню Grub нажимаем `E`. В открывшемся редакторе меню загрузки находим строку `linux vmlinuz...` и приводим её к следующему виду: `linux vmlinux... init=/bin/bash`.
- После загрузки в оболочку `bin/bash` с правами root добавляем пользователя в группу `wheel` или `sudo`:

```
usermod -a -G wheel your_name
```

```
usermode -a -G sudo your_name
```

- Можно добавить разрешение для самого пользователя в файл `sudoers` (вставить строку в конец):

```
your_name ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

- Если не разрешено использование утилиты su пользователями из групп `wheel` (`sudo`):

```
%wheel ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

ИЛИ:

```
%sudo ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

---

[Источник](https://losst.ru/oshibka-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-v-ubuntu)

Comment: Дело в том, что я работаю в WSL Ubuntu под Windows, и файл с логами там не ищется (возможно он в другой директории)